# Stop and restart workmanager

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I want to stop my WorkManager, when I call to somebody or call me and restart WorkManager, if call is done. Maybe, I can add a constraints, but I don`t know which ones to add. How can I do it?

Comment: There is [complete documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work) on this topic:

Comment: @GauravMall thats what the questions says..so I assume he's finished with part about calling and receiving call

Comment: @GauravMall it is not completely impossible to check the call state or to request something from work manager.

Comment: @GauravMall it is not the way how Broadcast works. You can process `PHONE_STATE` and `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` actions and then handle them on broadcast receiver that is able to choose between `TelephonyManager` states.

Comment: @GauravMall no-no, my dear friend. It gets notified when special actions occurs, like when you get incoming call or you end the call.

Comment: I know it does that, but it is not practical to do it with background works. Read some of the documentation and you will understand.

Comment: I know about background processing limitations. The question was in that, that QA want to stop `WorkManager`, to prevent any possible work. I don't say that it's impossible to forse it to do work, but the question was in "how to stop/restart".

Comment: Sorry, but I don`t hear about TelephonyManager. Thanks. I try it

Comment: @VadimFedchuk I'm actually interested if it still works. I want to check some code and will edit my answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to read Official Documentation: [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

You're probably looking for something like [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work).

If you need to handle a broadcast when user start or end the call you probably want to have a look for [`TelephonyManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager).

So you would be able to perform different work in different call stages you could have a closer look for [Device call state](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#CALL_STATE_IDLE).

So to be able to do something after getting a call you need to register a Broadcast Receiver that handles actions so in AndroidManifest file you need to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and then to register your receiver in manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

After that, you're able to override the `onReceive` method, get action with `intent.getAction()` and then to stop or restart your work manager if there is a need.

Then you can get the state:

```
intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
```

And after that, you can specify what to do if the state is `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`, `CALL_STATE_IDLE` or `CALL_STATE_RINGING`.

And then if you need to stop WorkManager from any work that could be started you could use:

```
WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag(*work_tag*);
```